# Find $f$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)^{e^x}=e$ and $f(x)+F(x)=x$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I need to find $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and $F$ an antiderivative of $f$. Find $f$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)^{e^x}=e$ and $f(x)+F(x)=x$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I thought that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)^{e^x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{e^xlnf(x)}$ and this is $e$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: Start by solving the differential equation $f(x) + F(x) = x$.  It might find it easier if you write it as $y' + y = x$, where $y = F(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x)+F'(x)=x$ so $(F(x)e^{x})'=xe^{x}$. Integrating this we get $e^{x}F(x)=(x-1)e^{x}+c$ or $F(x)=x-1+ce^{-x}$. Hence $f(x)=1-ce^{-x}$. Now $e^{x}\log(f(x)) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ and this gives $c=-1$. Hence $f(x)=1+e^{-x}$.